Cannot get live plot to re-render React Native UPlot/ChartJS
I am coding an android app with React Native that basically is a live high frequency pressure sensor grapher with which I'm hoping to graph data every 10-20ms. I have already achieved close to what I want using D3 with Skia, but this is just about too slow. Data every 40ms is a good live plot with minimal latency but the graphing often stutters which I don't like, and data every 10ms causes a significant latency between sensor and graphing. From research it looked like this was because I was using an SVG based grapher, and a canvas based one would be much better when it comes to speed and re-rendering.
I came across a github which claims to have made a wrapper around react-native-webview which is a canvas based grapher: https://github.com/dpwiese/react-native-canvas-charts/tree/main
I have managed to render graphs with both the ChartJS and UPlot examples and in both of them I can log my data to the console and it demonstrates that it is constantly updating while the graph remains static (unless I close and reopen the page, then it just comes up static again with the most recent data).
Below is the UPlot example (hopefully it formats properly, I haven't asked a question in stack overflow before):
import { UPlot } from "@dpwiese/react-native-canvas-charts/UPlot";
import Notification_Context from './Notification_Context';
import {useState, useEffect, useContext} from "react";



// Setting data
var originalDataX = [];
var originalDataY = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
  originalDataX.push(i);
  originalDataY.push(null);
};



// App/screen function
export default function Plotting_Experiment() {
  // Setting up hook to repeatedly update data values
  const [dataSetting, setDataSetting] = useState([originalDataX, originalDataY])



  // Importing pressure constantly updating pressure values
  const [pressureValue, connectionStatus] = useContext(Notification_Context);



  // Shifting dataset and adding new pressure value
  for (let i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
    originalDataY[i] = originalDataY[i+1];
  };
  originalDataY[24] = pressureValue;



  // Plotting settings
  const opts = {
    title: "My Chart",
    width: 800,
    height: 700,
    series: [
      {},
      {
        stroke: "red",
        width: 1,
      }],};



  // Updating the graph's input values everytime there is a new perssure reading
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(dataSetting);
    setDataSetting([
      originalDataX,
      originalDataY,
    ]);
  }, [pressureValue]);
  

  
  // Rendering the graph
  return(
    <UPlot opts={opts} data={dataSetting} style={{height: opts.height, width: opts.width}}/>
  );
}

